# EEVEE render not using GPU fully

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, performance

I am rendering PNG RGBA frames in EEVEE of a camera fly over a historic building modeled in Blender 2.80.74. PC specs: i7 with 20GB, 1Gb SSD and a GTX 1070 & GTX 1050. EEVEE uses only the GTX 1070. Each Frame takes in total on average 40 seconds to render and write to SSD. During these 40 seconds, the Task manager shows the GTX 1070 is 100% active for roughly 6 seconds and the CPU is 100% active for roughly 10 seconds. Any idea why GPU and/or CPU are not fully used in the 40 seconds and what i can do to reduce render time? See Task Manager output (60 sec charts) below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rendering task are more complicated then CPU and GPU usage graph show.

When Blender encounter a bottle neck, sometime it is not the multi-threading task like rendering tiles but a calculation in a single process thread.

And some time because the RAM speed isn't fully catch up with CPU and GPU, or sometime some I/O waiting of hardware is locking the process.

It is hard to tell what is the bottle neck from the scene, especially you just show a task manager image with low resolution. From your graph, the RAM is actually drop for a large amount during the processing. I would guess that Blender is dealing with quite large of detail from your scene, and the thing **dealing** in Blender is often single python thread which can't not benefit from multi-core CPU.

For speed up the rendering, there are a bunch of option in performance panel, you can try to render single image to see the speed difference.